# Pretty print and substitute numpy arrays

Tags: python, json, numpy, pretty-print

Imagine am pretty printing a JSON-decoded object that has the structure:

```
{Stack
   Layer
     Material
       <array>
}
```

Where these variables correspond to a hierarchy of structures in a simulation.  At the end of the hierarchy, there's a numpy array object.  These arrays tend to be really large, so I'd rather not print them explicitly, but kind of print a summary.  So instead of:

```
{Stack
   Layer
     Material
       array([1,2,3,4,5......])
}
```

It would look like:

```
{Stack
   Layer
     Material
       array: dtype, shape
}
```

IE pretty print would not print the full array, but just summarize it's information by printing the shape and datatype.  Is such customization available in prettyprint?

Comment: Hmm ok. Python 2.7 or Python 3?

Comment: I wonder if you're still monitoring this question... I've added a new answer that uses a simple decorator, and leaves the `pprint` module untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm a molecular biologist and not a professional programmer, so bear with me.
In my very naïf opinion, which you shouldn't take into much consideration, one of the options is to make your own version of pprint, aware of `numpy`'s `ndarray` objects, and printing them the way you want them.

What I did, and it worked with me, is to open the `pprint` module (under the `Lib` directory) and create a modified copy, like this:

(I pasted the working, modified code on pastebin, you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/3Yz44ZAB) )

First, in the import section, have it try to import numpy's `ndarray`, by adding:

```
try:
    from numpy import ndarray
    np_arrays = True
except ImportError:
    np_arrays = False
```

Then, in the definition of the `_format` function, right **after** this:

```
# This is already there
if self._depth and level > self._depth:
    write(rep)
    return
```

(so at line 154 in my copy, after the imports) you should add:

```
# Format numpy.ndarray object representations
if np_arrays and issubclass(typ, ndarray):
    write('array(dtype:' + str(object.dtype))
    write('; shape: ' + str(object.shape) + ')')
    return
```

(then the function continues with, `r = getattr(typ, "__repr__", None)`...)

Now save this script in the same Lib directory where pprint is, with a new name like i.e. `mypprint.py` and then try:

```
from mypprint import pprint
pprint.pprint(object_with_np.arrays)
```

Comment: Edited, I added a link to the working code on pastebin, so it's easier.

Comment: Thanks, works nicely!

What I'll probably do is just add a keyword argument to pprint so that I can turn this behavior on and off (ie it passes down into the _format function that you've modified).  

Thanks for going through this for me, appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! I should comment that I had just modified a little the script, to put the `;` between dtype and shape with the second `write()`. Nothing of importance, the output is the same, just one less `+ ''`.

Comment: It's probably also possible to monkey patch pprint (although I'll just use the whole modified module like you suggested).  For example:

from mypprint import pprint
pprint._format = newformat

Where newformat is the format function you overloaded

Comment: Yes, exactly... I just thought that if you need this often, you might as well patch it for good :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still monitoring this question?
I've been thinking and, if you want to make it more portable, you could just leave the `pprint` module untouched, and just add a decorator for the `_format` method in your script, i.e.:

```
import pprint
import numpy as np

def ndarray_catch(original_format_func):
    def _format(*argv):
        myobj = argv[1]
        if issubclass(type(myobj), np.ndarray):
            array_text = 'array(dtype:' + str(myobj.dtype)
            array_text +='; shape:' + str(myobj.shape) + ')'
            argv = list(argv)
            argv[1] = array_text
        return original_format_func(*argv)
    return _format

pprint.PrettyPrinter._format = ndarray_catch(pprint.PrettyPrinter._format)
```

Try it with:

```
my_list = [1, 2, {3:4, 5:"I like to import antigravity"}, \
           ["this is a very very long text", "smalltext", 
            np.array([[7,8], [9, 10]])], ("here", "there", ["everywhere"])]    
pprint.pprint(my_list)
```

The output is:

```
[1,
 2,
 {3: 4, 5: 'I like to import antigravity'},
 ['this is a very very long text',
  'smalltext',
  'array(dtype:int32; shape:(2L, 2L))'],
 ('here', 'there', ['everywhere'])]
```

Comment: Hey, yes I'm still monitoring, thanks for adding to it.  I've noticed that when I pass an array of type "object", I get errors.  We shouldn't have this datatype in our results anyway, so it's actually good that it got hungup, but do you get the same behavior.  We also probably are going to have to pretty nested print pandas objects as well, so do you happen to have an idea how to catch those?  Probably same idea, isssubclass(obj, pandas.PandasObject) or something

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes, you can expand the decorator to catch any other data type you'd like pretty printed. What the decorator does is just to catch the object if it's a `ndarray`, and just hand a string describing it to the `_format` method. So you can expand on the decorator by catching more object types, and pass to `_format` just an already-pretty string instead.

Comment: @AdamHughes I tried with an array of type "object" and it worked (admittedly it was just `np.array([[1, 2], ["three", [4]]], dtype=object)`). Do you have a more complex example where it doesn't work? We can fix it then.

Comment: Ah, sorry looks like it's not the code, but in some of the custom string formatting I put in to the format string.

Comment: Oh the reason I put `*argv` but not `**kwargs` is that nowhere in `pprint` the `_format` module is passed with keywords, so it would serve no purpose right now. It might change in the future, with new versions of pprint (I also hope someone changes "object" to some other variable name there, lol).

Comment: Cool man, thanks.  I'll link back here when I have a demo that uses this soon in our project

Comment: @AdamHughes changed the nested wrapper's name to `_format` to preserve _format's `__name__` attribute, after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28004413/2962364). I don't think there's a need to import functools here, as the only other thing it does is to copy the docstring and there's none for `_format`.
I'm reading [this series of blog posts](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/how-you-implemented-your-python.html), which seem very interesting, on implementing decorators. In this case, however, I think you don't lose anything by doing it the simple closure way. Otherwise it's featuritis.