# How do I elegantly/efficiently write the __init__ function for a Python class that takes lots of instance variables?

Tags: python, class

Let's say you have a class that takes many (keyword) arguments, most of which are meant to be stored as instance variables:

```
class ManyInitVariables():
    def __init__(a=0, b=2, c=1, d=0, e=-1, ... , x=100, y=0, z=9):
```

How would you initialize them in `__init__`? You could do something like this:

```
class ManyInitVariables():
    def __init__(a=0, b=2, c=1, d=0, e=-1, ... , x=100, y=0, z=9):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        ...
        self.z = z
```

...but it would take a lot of typing! How could I get `__init__` to automatically *some* of the arguments it takes, noting that other arguments may not need to be assigned as instance variables?

Comment: If your class takes a whole bunch of positional arguments, it *could* be a sign that your class does too much, and that you might want to break it into components. A bunch of keyword arguments, on the other hand, is a different story.

Comment: @jme let's assume they are a bunch of keyword arguments (and I'll add that clarification to my post), because really this situation is coming up for me when I want a class to model something scientific that just has plenty of initial conditions to define

Comment: You really meant instance variables, not class variables, right?

Comment: @Roberto so I looked into what you said a bit more, and you are right, I have made the changes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure there are many other similar solutions out there on the web for this very common issue, but this is one, for example:

```
import functools
import inspect

def absorb_args(f):
    args, _, _, defs = inspect.getargspec(f)
    args = args[1:]  # ignore the leading `self`
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def do_absorb(self, *a, **k):
        ndefs = len(args) - len(a) + 2
        for name, value in zip(args, a + defs[-ndefs:]):
            setattr(self, name, value)
        for name, value in k.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
        return f(self, *a, **k)
    return do_absorb
```

Added: I've been asked to explain this further, but, there's a lot going on here if you're not skilled at Python!-).

`functools.wraps` is a decorator to help make better decorators, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps -- not directly germane to the question but useful to support interactive `help` and tools based on functions' docstrings.  Get into the habit of **always** using it when writing a function decorator that (the most common case) wraps the decorated function, and you won't regret it.

The `inspect` module is the only right way to do introspection in modern Python.  `inspect.getargspec` in particular gives you information on what arguments a function accepts, and what the default values for them are, if any (the two bits of info I'm ignoring, by assigning them to `_`, are about `*a` and `**k` special args, which this decorator doesn't support).  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html?highlight=getargspec#inspect.getargspec for more.

`self`, by convention, is always the first arg to a method (and this decorator is meant for methods only:-).  So, the first `for` loop deals with positional args (whether explicitly given in the call or defaulting to default values); then, the second `for` loop deals with named args (that one, I hope, is simpler to grasp:-).  `setattr` of course is the precious built-in function which sets an attribute with a variable name, https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr for more.

Incidentally, if you only care to use this in `__init__` (as you see in the example below, `absorb_attrs` per se has no such constraint), then write a **class** decorator which singles out the class's `__init__` for this treatment, and apply that class decorator to the class itself.

Also, if your class's `__init__` has no work left to do once args are "absorbed" in this way, you must still define the (decorated) `__init__`, but its body can be limited to a docstring explaining the arguments (I personally prefer to always also have a `pass` statement in such cases, but that's a personal style issue).

And now, back to the original answer, with an example...!-)

And then, e.g, something like

```
class Struggle(object):

    @absorb_args
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, bab='bo', bip='bop'):
        self.d = a + b

    @absorb_args
    def setit(self, x, y, z, u=23, w=45):
        self.t = x + y

    def __str__(self):
        attrs = sorted(self.__dict__)
        r = ['%s: %s' % (a, getattr(self, a)) for a in attrs]
        return ', '.join(r)

s = Struggle('fee', 'fie', 'foo', bip='beeeeeep')
s.setit(1, 2, 3, w=99)
print(s)
```

would print

```
a: fee, b: fie, bab: bo, bip: beeeeeep, c: foo, d: feefie, t: 3, u: 23, w: 99, x: 1, y: 2, z: 3
```

as desired.

My only excuse for "reinventing the wheel" this way (rather than scouring the web for a solution) is that the other evening my wife and co-author Anna (only ever woman winner of the Frank Willison Memorial Award for contribution to the Python community, BTW:-) asked me about it (we are, slowly alas!, writing the 3rd edition of "Python in a Nutshell") -- it took me 10 minutes to code this (sorry, no tests yet:-) while in the same 10 minutes she (despite being a very skilled web-searcher:-) could not locate an existing solution on the web.  And, this way I need not worry about copyright issues if I want to post it here, include it in the next Nutshell, present about it at OSCON or Pycon, and so forth...:-)

Comment: @user2864740 I agree. Alex, could I have more of an explanation of your solution (perhaps something like comments), simply in order to make your answer more "self-contained". At the moment, I suppose, I would have to go google what what you are doing (for example, why use functools?) but maybe that's not a bad thing...I am not sure.

Comment: @user89, not sure -- people may hate the technical concept of making an equivalent of Ruby's `attr_reader` available in Python, or they may hate the personal and anecdotal info I added.

Comment: @user2864740 , I can surely add further instruction -- I **should** be writing the 3rd ed of the Nutshell instead, but it **is** more fun to post here:-).  But I think I'll compromise and mostly just add links to the relevant, excellent online docs rather than copy and past them or paraphrase them:-)

Comment: @user2864740, big edit just done to add both verbiage and links, enjoy!  I've been "around programming" longer than I bet most readers have been "around" at all:-), even though I started my career as an integrated-circuit and HW system designer and I'm practically entirely self-taught in programming.  Good web search engines, and later the ability to buy and download e-books in a snap, have made it SO easy to find out about things that I can hardly believe it... in MY time, we had to walk uphill to the library, then uphill back home, in the snow...!-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli Thanks for taking the time with the updates! I missed the snow and hills (whew!), but I did have to turn the _floppy_ disk when booting ;-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli oh wow, in my short venture with decorators I never thought about how introspection is (of course!!) totally lost with closures. That's... cool and worrying at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: Not that it's likely to matter, but it seems to me that you could move the `inspect.getargspec` call out of the inner function (allowing the inner function to pick up those values from the closure).  This way you don't call getargspec every time you call the decorated function.  It also seems like you could simplify by changing the signature of the inner function to `def do_absorb(self, *a, **kw): ...`.  This would allow you to drop a bunch of the slices with a few other tweaks.

Comment: @mgilson, yep, both worthwhile ideas -- I did say I only spent 10 minutes on this (I shd have taken 15:-)... ok, editing per your ideas, w.credit.

Comment: Well, I figured if you're gonna be putting it in your book ... ;-)  Also, I removed the line where you give me credit.  It just broke up the flow of the post for no real benefit (but I appreciate the sentiment -- Thanks).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of years later, Python 3.7 introduced the [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which allows you to define a class like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ManyInitVariables:
    a: int = 0
    b: int = 2
    ...
    z: 'typing.Any' = 9
```

This will automatically take care of setting the instance attributes.

There's also [make_dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass):

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, field

attributes = [('a', int, 0), ('b', int, 2), ..., ('z', 'typing.Any', 9)]

ManyInitVariables = make_dataclass(
    'ManyInitVariables', 
    [(attr_name, attr_type, field(default=attr_default)) 
     for attr_name, attr_type, attr_default in attributes])
```

Arguments that should *not* be assigned as instance attributes can be marked as "init-only variables" using [`dataclasses.InitVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables). These can then be processed in a [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method.

Comment: I’ve been following the dataclasses library since it’s near inception, when it was first introduced to stdlib in 3.7. It’s a great library, seems to be a perfect fit for the ask above.