# Class __init__ attributes, DRY vs IDE functinality

Tags: python, class, ide, initialization, dry

What's the proper way to follow the DRY rule in class `__init__` method?

I know this two ways:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Bar:
    _fields = ['x', 'y', 'z']

    def __init__(self, x, y, z=None):
        for field in self.__class__._fields:
            setattr(self, field, locals()[field])
```

The method in Foo is very repetitive, you have to type each attribute name three times, it gets quite exhausting doing this in classes with even small number of attributes and names not so lengthy.

On the other hand, the method used in Bar is way shorter, but has the draw back of constant warnings from the IDE's stating that there's 'unresolved references'. And also this method doesn't allow using the dot operator functionality in the IDE's to auto-complete the attributes.

I'm looking for what to do to create the classes not repeating attributes names all over and still be able to use some functionality from the IDE's.

I'm using PyCharm as my IDE, but I would happily change to any other if there's support for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Use the first version. If you find yourself writing classes with many variables consider refactoring your code and splitting your class into smaller and more targeted classes.

Comment: It's not that I'm writing classes with many attributes, but every time I have to write an attribute I have to type it's name 3 times.

Comment: This is unrelated to DRY - you're assigning *different things*!

Comment: Alex Martelli shared a decorator in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004358/how-do-i-elegantly-efficiently-write-the-init-function-for-a-python-class-th/28004413#28004413) which automatically assigns arguments to `__init__` to the class instance. But I agree with @alfasin: if you've got a lot of arguments to `__init__`, it's time to refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "On the other hand, the method used in Bar is way shorter"

Not really... In your example it is the same number of lines and WAY more characters.  Of course, this might not be the case if you're passing LOTS of arguments to the constructor, but... once you start having too many arguments in the constructor then you're about due for a refactor to figure out how to cut down the number of arguments anyway...

Use the first version.  Your future self/collaborators will thank you for it<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Actually, your future collaborators probably won't know to thank you... I suppose it might be more accurate to say that your future self/collaborators won't hunt you down to make your life miserable for writing hard to read code :-)</sup>